Springboot 3.2 webflux java21 ReactiveMongoDB Mongo v7. How to make the same in compass by code with SpringData in ReactiveRepository?
In Compass work fine below filter collection:
{
    "code": "BASE",
    "channel": "CW",
    "touchpoint": "AB",
    "virtual.sizes": {"$elemMatch": {"productId": "PV_S"}}
}

and Project (to print other properties of collection in result):
{ "type":1, "name":2, "color":3, "code":4, "channel":5, "touchpoint":6, "validProductDates":7, "virtual.sizes.$": 8}

How to implement it my interface myReactiveRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<myData, String>?
I'm looking how it can be done but nothing I found, actually I used default method of ReactiveMongoRepository or using @Query annotation to create my methods in my interface of ReactiveMongo
Thanks a lot.
